# Save the chosen image from input in an object state and render it on the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

It only works when I change my image `src` to `AddProjects`, not when it is `AddProjects.Img`, which is what I want.

How can I tell React that the URL should be saved in the `AddProjects.Img`? Here is my code:

```js
export default function AddProjects() {
  const [AddProjects, setAddProjects] = useState({
    name: "",
    Discription: "",
    git: "",
    Img: "",
  });
  // const [imgAdd,setImgAdd] = useState()
  const inputFile = useRef(null);
  function handleChange(e) {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setAddProjects((newProjects) => ({
      ...newProjects,
      [name]: value,
    }));
  }
  function imgChange(e) {
    console.log(e.target.files);
    setAddProjects(URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]));
  }

  console.log(AddProjects);
  return (
    <div className="AddProjects">
      <form>
        <h2>Add New Project</h2>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Project Name..."
          value={AddProjects.name}
          name="name"
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Project Discription..."
          value={AddProjects.Discription}
          name="Discription"
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Git Repository/Code..."
          value={AddProjects.git}
          name="git"
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <input
          type="file"
          accept="image/jpg,image/jpeg"
          name="Img"
          onChange={imgChange}
          ref={inputFile}
        />
        <button type="button" onClick={() => inputFile.current.click()}>
          Add New Image
        </button>
        <button type="submit">Submit Project</button>
      </form>
      <img src={AddProjects.Img} alt="" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `imgChange` function is the problem here, as you are compelty replacing your object state with the image URL. Do so instead:

```js
function imgChange(e) {
  setAddProjects({ ...AddProjects, Img: URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]) });
}
```